# jQuery: Find occurence/position of class on page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to find the occurence/position of a clicked class on the page.

HTML:

```
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #1 -->
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #2 -->
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #3 -->
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #4 -->
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #5 -->
<div class="myclass"></div> <!-- OCCURENCE #6 -->
```

jQuery:

```
$('.myclass').click(function(event) {


    //OUTPUT 'This class is the X one on the page'

});
```

For example if I click on the class occurence #3, I want to know that this class is the 3rd one on the page. I dont want to add any other infos such as data-id or id tag. How can I do that using jQuery? I know that I can get the total number of time the class is found using .length but that's about it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$(".myclass").click(function(e) {
    var index = $(".myclass").index(this) + 1;
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gdcQv/

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about index. Cheers!